# Javascript: Iterate through list of objects and scale the values between known min and max

Tags: javascript, json, scale

I have a list of objects and I want to scale the values between a known min and max. So if the known min and max are 100, 800, I'd want the result to be as follows:

```
{'cat' : 1, 'dog' : 3, 'chimp' : 8} -> {'cat' : 100, 'dog' : 300, 'chimp' : 800}
```

The Python/pandas implementation looks like this

```
def scale_size(old_value):
        if numbers_df['raw_size'].max() == 1:
            return 150
        old_value = float(old_value)
        old_max = numbers_df['raw_size'].max()
        old_min = numbers_df['raw_size'].min()
        new_max = 150
        new_min = 20
        old_range = old_max - old_min
        new_range = new_max - new_min
        new_value =  (((old_value - old_min) * new_range) / old_range) + new_min

        return int(new_value)
```

Comment: how `'chimp' : 12` should be scaled?

Comment: Use the code from [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object?rq=1) and do the math on `p[key]` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a function to map your values from one range to another. To do this, you should do the following:

- Figure out the minimum and maximum of your current range (e.g. `(1,8)`)
- Figure out the minimum and maximum of the range to which you want to map the values (e.g. `(100,800)`)
- Map existing values from one range to another, by calculating the relative position in the old range and applying that relative position to the new range

#### Sample code

I'm sure there are more efficient and/or cleaner ways to achieve this, but this could be a decent starting point for what you want to do. On a side note, you could theoretically calculate the minimum and maximum of your current range by finding the smallest and largest values in your key-value pairs, however this might not be ideal for all cases.

```js
var oldVals = {'cat' : 1, 'dog' : 3, 'chimp' : 8};

function mapValues(oldMin, oldMax, newMin, newMax, values){
  var newVals = {};
  for (key in values){
    newVals[key] = (values[key] - oldMin) * (newMax - newMin) / (oldMax - oldMin) + newMin;
  }
  return newVals;
}

console.log(mapValues(1, 8, 100, 800, oldVals));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the factor by using the delta of max minus min of the wanted  and the given ranges and calculate a new value for every value in the object.

```js
var object = { cat: 1, dog: 3, chimp: 8 },
    min = 100,
    max = 800,
    minO = Math.min(...Object.values(object)),
    maxO = Math.max(...Object.values(object)),
    factor = (max - min) / (maxO - minO);

Object.keys(object).forEach(k => object[k] = (object[k] - minO) * factor + min);

console.log(object);
```